# How to fill all textboxes after click on gridview by making classLibrary?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to make a class library containing classes for common tasks.

I made such a class that worked very well on some forms but it have some errors that I can't trace down.

This is my code and it does the following:

- It accepts 3 parameters: form name, datagridview name and the textbox name prefixes.
- It counts the datagrid columns
- It takes the current row index
- It makes the array with a length corresponding to the number of columns
- It's looking in the form for all text boxes that have a name with prefix parameter + column name and set the value in it

Code:

```
Sub setRecordFieldToControl(ByVal root As Form, ByVal dgv As DataGridView, ByVal cntrlPreNam1 As String, ByVal cntrlPreNam2 As String)
    Dim j, k, z As Integer
    Dim s As String
    z = dgv.ColumnCount
    k = dgv.CurrentRow.Index
    j = 0
    Dim headTxt(z) As String
    For indx = 0 To z - 1
        headTxt(indx) = dgv.Columns(indx).HeaderText
    Next

    For Each i As Control In root.Controls
        If TypeOf i Is MaskedTextBox Or TypeOf i Is ComboBox Then
            For clm = 0 To z
                If i.Name = cntrlPreNam1 & headTxt(clm) Or i.Name = cntrlPreNam1 & headTxt(clm) Then

                    s = (dgv.Rows(k).Cells(j).Value)
                    i.Text = s
                    ' i.Text = dgv.Item(j, k).Value
                    j = j + 1
                    If j >= z Then
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

My problem is: on some forms I got this error:

> Index is out of range for line  **i.Text = s**

The error does not show up when I put something else in my text box, the error only appears when I put the s in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is probably in the line

```
For clm = 0 To z
```

It should read

```
For clm = 0 To z - 1
```

The column indexes range from 0 .. number_of_columns - 1.

---

**UPDATE**

There are several problems with your code:

- The logic seems wrong to me. You are looking for the column (`clm`) with the right name but then take the value of another column (`j`). Why?
- The variable names are not speaking and are even misleading (e.g. `i` for a `Control`).
- You have nested loops with an O(n^2) behavior. See [Big O Notation](https://www.google.ch/search?q=Big%20O%20Notation).

I suggest rewriting it. Use a dictionary for the possible control names, that stores the corresponding column indexes by name. Dictionaries have a nearly constant access speed. In other words: Lookups are very fast.

```
Sub SetRecordFieldToControl(ByVal root As Form, ByVal dgv As DataGridView, _
          ByVal cntrlPrefix1 As String, ByVal cntrlPrefix2 As String)
    Dim currentRowIndex As Integer = dgv.CurrentRow.Index
    Dim columnDict = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

    For i As Integer = 0 To dgv.ColumnCount - 1
        Dim headerText As String = dgv.Columns(i).HeaderText
        columnDict.Add(cntrlPrefix1 & headerText, i)
        columnDict.Add(cntrlPrefix2 & headerText, i)
    Next

    For Each cntrl As Control In root.Controls
        If TypeOf cntrl Is MaskedTextBox Or TypeOf cntrl Is ComboBox Then
            Dim columnIndex As Integer
            If columnDict.TryGetValue(cntrl.Name, columnIndex) Then
                Dim value As Object
                value = dgv.Rows(currentRowIndex).Cells(columnIndex).Value
                If Not value Is Nothing Then
                    cntrl.Text = value.ToString()
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: i fixed it now but it give me this error again:"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"

Comment: You are looking for the column (clm) with the right name but then take the value of another column (j). Why? Dont' you have a problem with your logic?

Comment: thanks for helping me . i am beginner with using this codes . i use your code and test it in my program ,but still give me the same error

Comment: Use the Debugger to track down the problem. Set a breakpoint on the first line (`For i As Integer ...`) and then step through the code, inspect the variables, etc.

Comment: i cant find why that error is show for me i do what you tell me but i at end was equal my text boxes i am really astounding.....

Comment: "Index is out of range" means that one of the indexes `z`, `indx`, `clm`, `k` or `j` in your code example exceeds the allowed range. It cannot be the line `i.Text = s` beacause that one does not use any index. If you single-step through the code you should see which index is responsible for the disaster.

Comment: hello ,i use the following code that you give it to me when i make the line **cntrl.Text = value.ToString()** comment there will be no error , i use the ** MsgBox(cntrl.Name + cntrl.Text + value.ToString)** there is no error to , but the error only shown to me when i give some value to **cntrl** , even when i use the **cntrl.Enabled = False** the program give me no error

Comment: Have you defined a TextChanged or similar event that is triggered when you change the Text? The error could happen there. Are you using DataBinding for `cntl`? This also could lead to an error somewhere else.

Comment: yes i defined textchange for text boxes and when i remove text change the code do not give any error how can i disable textchane event for awhile at run time to solove my problem??

Comment: See [AddHandler and RemoveHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yyk8z93(v=vs.90).aspx). You could also haven an appropriate `If` statement within the `TextChanged` event handler in combination with as Boolean flag to temporarily disable some logic.